# What is the "Built-in Texture2D"? How to reduce its size or remove it?

Tags: unity, android, build-process, build

I am building an APK in Unity. The build log says this:

```
Used Assets and files from the Resources folder, sorted by uncompressed size:

 9.3 mb  3.7% Built-in Texture2D:
```

My 2 questions are:

1. What and where is the **Built-in Texture2D** ?
2. How do I remove or reduce the size of this **Built-in Texture2D** ?

I want to reduce the size of those texture2D files if I know where they are.

---

[There is some answer on the web](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1382218/whats-the-huge-built-in-texture2d-without-name-in.html) saying that one form of this **Built-in Texture2D** could be the splash screen.

But, I don't have any customized splash screen, and only use the default Unity splash screen, which is not too big.

---

I have tried to enable the option **Deployment Build** when building the APK. But, that does not remove or reduce the size the **Built-in Texture2D** at all.

Comment: In Unity3D, a Built-in Texture2D is a pre-defined texture that is included with the Unity engine and can be used in a variety of ways, such as for creating materials, GUI elements, and particle systems. These textures include things like checkerboards, gradients, and noise patterns that can be used as a starting point for creating custom textures. They can be accessed and used in the Unity editor by selecting "Import Package > Built-in Shaders" and then selecting the texture from the "Standard" or "Legacy" shader menu.

Comment: @FabioS: that looks like it could make a good answer. Can you elaborate on whether or not there's a way to exclude these textures from the built version of the game?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is Unity's built-in asset bundle system. Unfortunately, I don't have a step-by-step guide for it, but in the past, that's how I reduced large APK files.

Here are a couple of links that could be useful:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Building.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html

Answer (score 1):

In Unity3D, a Built-in Texture2D is a pre-defined texture included with the Unity engine and can be used in various ways, such as for creating materials, GUI elements, and particle systems. These textures include checkerboards, gradients, and noise patterns that can be used as a starting point for creating custom textures. They can be accessed and used in the Unity editor by selecting "Import Package > Built-in Shaders" and then choosing the texture from the "Standard" or "Legacy" shader menu.

To reduce the size of an APK, the first thing that comes to mind is Unity's built-in asset bundle system. Unfortunately, I don't have a step-by-step guide for it, but in the past, that's how I reduced large APK files. Here are a couple of links that could be useful:

[docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Building.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Building.html)

[docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html)